# We both vs both of us

Tags: grammar, quantifiers

The book "Practical English Usage" by Michael Swan, page 155, contains the following guidance:

[image]

I wonder if instead of an object pronoun we had a subject pronoun, would be possible to use **to be + pronoun?**; eg:

> Why are they both asking silly things?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have easy access to the full context. Is it the case that Swan's text specifically says *...after pronouns used as **objects***, but not after pronouns used as ***subjects***? Surely ***we both*** know that's nonsense! (And if there are a couple more users reading this, I'm sure ***they both*** know that too! :)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably Swan meant that Pronoun + *both* should not be the complement of *be*. He phrased it as "not used in complements" but that is too broad, because it can be nested within a clause that is the complement of *be*: "The problem was that they both were late."